# getting values from array in loop

Tags: wordpress

Im looping through some posts in order to get the galleries attached to each post.  I would like to collect all urls in another array that will only contain these urls.

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if (get_post_gallery()) :


                    $gallery_images = get_post_gallery_images();

                    // In each loop $gallery_images will contain a new
                    // array of urls. I would like to add these urls to collect all urls in another array.

                    ?>
                    <?php
        endif;
    }
}?>
```

Im sure this must be simple but I cant figure it out. Help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to collect all urls in $gallery_images array ?

```
$gallery_images[] = get_post_gallery_images(get_the_ID());
```

Also i believe get_post_gallery_images() requires the post ID or post object as argument . See here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery_images

Comment: Thank you! Worked!